# Shows only black screen when moving to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I don't know what I've done, but after I restart the Android Studio and when i run the app, it just shows only black screen when I'm calling new activity from previous activity.
The app is running good before I restarted the Android Studio.
I don't find where the wrong code is. There is no error based on the IDE.

I have this in onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

I have launched the activity by this code:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, homeActivity.class));
```

in the previous class

I've seen many answers here, but do not solved my problem.

**EDIT**

[image]

Screenshot after calling the homeActivity

Comment: Do clear one thing, previous activity get shown properly but when you launch HomeActvity then only you are getting black screen, is it ? also check context.startActivity(new Intent(context, homeActivity.class)); homeActivity.class should be HomeActivity.class

Comment: homeActivity.class is just right. Class is just named with starting small character

Comment: try clean and rebuild

Comment: I've tried it several times

Comment: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);` you are calling this from homeActivity onCreate right ?, if yes please check the layout file if it has proper views

Comment: It has. I really don't know what or where is the problem.

Comment: Yes I'm calling it from homeActivity onCreate

Comment: can you share the screenshot of black screen how does that look like, will help to guess the problem. Also share the homeactivity class

Comment: See edited post.

Comment: also do share the homeactivity java code

Comment: Try one thing, make your HomeActivity as launcher and then run the app directly, see if you still getting the black screen, by doing so we will move one step forward. It is just for our testing purpose.

Comment: I can't post the code here. Its too long

Comment: Okay, but I've tried calling other activities and it is not blacked screen.

Comment: We have black screen issue for HomeActivity right, so lets make that as a launch activity and re run the app

Comment: what I am trying, if homeactivity works fine if we declare that as launcher activity, then issue is in previous activity from where you are launching homeactivity

Comment: I think there is no issue in the previous activity. I tried to display other activity, and it works fine. The homeActivity is the only problem. I can send the code via google drive later.

Comment: did you try what I suggested ? if not can you please do that .. just you need to change in manifest file.

Comment: I've tried to make the homeActivity as a launch activity

Comment: It is black screen as it is.

Comment: I have fragments here, I don't know if there is problem in my fragments.

Comment: Then for sure there is issue in homeActivity itself.

Comment: Yes I think so. But, what part or what line of code usually it is?

Comment: that only can be found if you share the home activity class. specially oncreate and onResume method. atleast share onCreate method first

Comment: @MikaelFaire please let me know if you want to share the code, or found the solution. I am waiting here if I can provide some input to solve the issue.

Comment: @MikaelFaire please update your question with `activity_home.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Follow `CamelCase` for naming conventions for Java classes check `homeActivity.class --> HomeActivity.class`
- Ensure you define `homeActivity.class` in your `manifest.xml`

  ```
  <application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:installLocation="auto"
  tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
  android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  // ... Other activity
      <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  // ... Other meta-data & services.
  </application>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try create another activity with the same layout and class, but name it by the big letter.